# maven pom.xml after creation spring basics, getting an error

Tags: maven

maven pom.xml after creation spring basics, I am getting an error.

Error from maven:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0
Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4
Failed to read artifact descriptor for jmock:jmock:jar:1.1.0
Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.4
Failed to read artifact descriptor for mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.0.5
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.appfuse:appfuse-hibernate:jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.appfuse:appfuse-spring:war:2.0-SNAPSHOT
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.appfuse:appfuse-spring:warpath:2.0-SNAPSHOT
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-mock:jar:2.0.6
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.subethamail:subethasmtp-wiser:jar:1.2
Plugin org.appfuse:maven-warpath-plugin:2.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.appfuse:maven-warpath-plugin:jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `mvn -U clean install`

When you add `-U` you force maven to look for updates in remote repositories.

Comment: I am running in IntelliJ not command prompt, How I can run